# install Web Deploy tool using puppet

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I am automating the deployment of our web application build using puppet.
I have added scripts for installing .Net and configuring IIS web server in the .pp file . I also need to install Microsoft WebDeployment tool 2.0 as the deployment command uses msdeploy. can you help me with the puppet script required to install Microsoft WebDeployment tool 2.0

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to install anything, especially on Windows. One way to make life easier is to [use chocolatey as a package manager](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/chocolatey/chocolatey). You could then use the following resource to install Web Deploy 2.x:

```
package { 'msdeploy':
  provider => 'chocolatey',
  ensure   => latest
}
```